# WPF TreeView more than one list in HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

My model is like so:

```
public class CPFF
{
     public CMC Cmc { get; set; }
}

public class CMC 
{
     public List<CMCRecord> recordList { get; set; }
}

public class CMCRecord
{
     public string name { get; set; }
     public List<param> recordHeader { get; set; }
     public List<param> paramList { get; set; }
     public List<CmcStruct> structList { get; set; }
     public bool IsEmptyRecord { get; set; }
     public CpffConsts.CpffProjectVersion cpffProjectVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Xaml:

```
<TreeView  DataContext="{Binding Cpff1StProjectObject}" SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_OnSelectedItemChanged" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
  <TreeViewItem Header="CMC" >
    <TreeViewItem Header="RecordList" ItemsSource="{Binding Cmc.recordList}" >
      <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type types:CMCRecord}" ItemsSource="{Binding paramList}">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name, StringFormat={}CMCRecord : {0}}" />
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeViewItem>
  </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type types:param}">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name, StringFormat={}Name : {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=type, StringFormat={}Type : {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=description, StringFormat={}Description : {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=defaultValue, StringFormat={}DefaultValue : {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=domain_name, StringFormat={}domain_name : {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=notes, StringFormat={}Notes : {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=offset, StringFormat={}Offset : {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=bytes, StringFormat={}Bytes : {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=size, StringFormat={}Size : {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=min, StringFormat={}Min : {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=max, StringFormat={}Max : {0}}" />
  </StackPanel>
 </<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type types:param}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name, StringFormat={}Name : {0}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=type, StringFormat={}Type : {0}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=description, StringFormat={}Description : {0}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=defaultValue, StringFormat={}DefaultValue : {0}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=domain_name, StringFormat={}domain_name : {0}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=notes, StringFormat={}Notes : {0}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=offset, StringFormat={}Offset : {0}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=bytes, StringFormat={}Bytes : {0}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=size, StringFormat={}Size : {0}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=min, StringFormat={}Min : {0}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=max, StringFormat={}Max : {0}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>>
```

This is how my tree look like:
[image]

Since CMCRecord Contains more than one list I would like to reflect it into the tool.
However since ItemSource in the HierarchicalDataTemplate is bound to paramlist, 
How can I show more than one list inside my TreeView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a union of the various lists as a list of type object (i.e. `List<object>`) and set that as the `Children` target in your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and use WPF type inference to determine the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to be used, much like you have done for type `param`